# Wordpress search function for custom post type only

Tags: wordpress

I've got a function added in functions.php to improve the search functionality in my directory section: http://www.highwaysindustry.com/?post_type=directory_listings&s=king

However, with the following enabled, it overrides the search for the rest of the website also: http://www.highwaysindustry.com

This particular function I would prefer it to be targeted for the directory search only.

Function in functions.php

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
global $wpdb;

if ( empty( $search ) )
return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

$q = $wp_query->query_vars;
$n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

$search =
$searchand = '';

foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
$term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );

$search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$term}[[:>:]]')";

$searchand = ' AND ';
}

if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
$search = " AND ({$search}) ";
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
$search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
}

return $search;
}

add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 1000, 2 );
```

Snippet of my directory-search.php which the form on /Directory uses:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'directory_listings',
        's'    => $s,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'membership_type',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order' => "DESC"
                    ,
                ),
            ),
        );
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="directory-banner">
            <img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/highways/images/directory-banner.jpg" alt="" title="" />
            <h1><?php echo $s; ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I currently have the function defined above commented out, when enabled it's a lot more specific, for example, searching "King" would only provide back 2 results. Right now the generic search provides too many unspecific results.

Comment: if i understand correctly your code modifies parts other than the serach results page. check if the current page is a search page with is_search()

Comment: It's not. Further down for the actual results it's using the standard: $query=new WP_Query($args);

Comment: You could also post this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ which is dedicated to wordpress.

Comment: Are you essentially just trying to use custom search logic on a specific page/portion of your site, and the standard search elsewhere?

Comment: @rnevius yes that is what I want to do, however this simply put in the functions.php file alters the search for the entire site as there is no current configuration telling it to only be for the directory search. the directory search .php file simply uses a standard loop but with custom parameters. I am unsure how to change the searching in the directory to things like title only, this is what I am attempting here.

Comment: Based on the first URL you've provided in your post I can say that you've added a hidden input field to the directory listing search form. Now in `__search_by_title_only` check if the query var `post_type` contains only directory_listings, if it does then continue with the rest of the function else `return $search`

Comment: Ah yes ok, I am getting somewhere. I've now got it to run the function only when the post type is: directory_listings. Now, in addition to my original question, the search is a little too specific. There is a company called blakedale, if you search just blake you won't get the result. Any method to increase the method of the returned result(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other 2 answers are also worth investigating. However I'll stick to your solution.

To search only directory_listings post type, tweak the function as shown below

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
global $wpdb;

if ( empty( $search ) )
return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

$q = $wp_query->query_vars;

// post_type query var has other posts types as well, return default search
if( ! 'directory_listings' == $q['post_type'] )
    return $search    

// We are here, it means post_type var contains only directory_listings 
// continue with the rest of the code
........
```

Answering your 2nd query

> There is a company called blakedale, if you search just blake you won't get the result. Any method to increase the method of the returned result(s).

The regexp being used in the code below searches for full words hence "blake" doesn't return any results

```
$search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$term}[[:>:]]')";
```

You need to either change the regexp or use SQL LIKE

```
$search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%{$term}%')";
```

P.S: I haven't tested the line of code above, so it may need polishing.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using `pre_get_posts` ?

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search && $_GET['post_type'] == 'directory_listings') {
      // add custom meta / tax queries
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .

```
 $query_args = array( 'post_type' => 'directory_listings', 'tax_query' => array() );

 if ( !empty( $search_terms ) ) {
    $query_args['s'] = $search_terms;
 }

 if ( !empty( $search_terms ) ) {
    $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'directory_listings',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $news_category
       )
   );
 }

 $my_posts = new WP_Query( $query_args );

 if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) { // etc

 }
```